# Multiple key register event PyQT5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, keyevent

I have a program programming with Pyqt5 in which I would like to register some keys simoultaneously;for example, up+right to go to the upper diagonal.

The problem is that with the pressEvent only accept the first key.

Also I use QPygletWidget, but I can not register the push_handlers event from pyglet to PyQt5.

````
from PyQt5 import  QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
     def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        
     def keyPressEvent(self, e, autorep=False):
         # print(e.key)
         # self.widget.key_pressed = e.key()
        print(e.key())
         # self.widget.key_pressed = None

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_()) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `QKeySequence` doesn't work for sequences that don't contain CTRL.

You can use `keyPressEvent` and `keyReleaseEvent` to keep track what keys is currently pressed and not released yet.

```
from PyQt5 import  QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self._keys = {Qt.Key_Up: False, Qt.Key_Right: False}

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() in [Qt.Key_Up, Qt.Key_Right]:
            self._keys[event.key()] = True
            if self._keys[Qt.Key_Up] and self._keys[Qt.Key_Right]:
                self.onUpRight()

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() in [Qt.Key_Up, Qt.Key_Right]:
            self._keys[event.key()] = False

    def onUpRight(self):
        print("onUpRight")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Be aware that if hold a key longer than some threshold (a second I guess) it sends sequences of `keyPressEvent` `keyReleaseEvent` as if you repeatedly pressed a button, so `onUpRight` will be called multiple times.